# How to generate several Enumerators out of a single Enumerator (partition, split, ..)

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, enumerator, loops

Is it possible to create several `Enumerators` out of a single `Enumerator` ?
What I'm looking for is the equivalent of `List.partition` that returns a `(List[A], List[A])` , such as

```
List().partition(_.age >= 18)
```

So ideally, I'd like to apply a transformation on an Enumerator that allows me to partition the data so that I get a `(Enumerator[T], Enumerator[T])` pair.

Is that easily doable using Play's Iteratee API ?

The closest thing I found is the `Enumeratee.grouped` method, which allows to group inputs, but as far as I understand, if all I want is 2 partitions (groups), I'll have to consume the entire `Enumerator`to get a result. But I'd like the resulting Enumerators to be fed asynchronously from the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `List`, `Enumerator` doesn't represent a collection of data, but rather a data source that an `Iteratee` can be connected to. Data is streamed to the `Iteratee` as the `Iteratee` consumes the input. Because of this, it isn't well defined how the two `Enumerator` instances returned by this `Enumerator.partition` would behave. If the `Iteratee` consuming the first `Enumerator` is ready for more input, but the second isn't, what happens? Does the first one just have to wait? Does data get buffered up for the second one? What happens if one of the two `Iteratee` instances says it doesn't need any more input, or dies with an error? Do we kill the other one? Do we let it keep going, throwing away the data originally meant for the dead `Iteratee`?

Because of this, there can't really be a single canonical `partition` method, like there is for `List`. You could certainly write one, that behaves the way you want it to, but in actual practice it might be easier to have a single `Iteratee` do all the processing. If you are looking for `partition` because you want to run the two streams in parallel, you probably want to use Akka. If you just want to have the pipelined parallelism that the Iteratee API provides, you could have an `Enumeratee[Whatever, Either[Whatever]]` that would allow later `Enumeratee` instances to only convert the part of the stream that they need to.

If you are willing to indulge in the black magic that is monad transformers, then I think there might be a way to use something like Haskell's `EitherT`. But don't do that.